# Undo Git commit

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed all files with the command

```
git commit -m "Message" .
```

Where I wanted to actually run

```
git commit -m "Message" ./file
```

I haven't yet done a git push. How can I undo the last commit so all of these files don't get pushed?

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit)

Comment: @gpullen: your solution worked. If you add it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: No prob glad it helped.                                                             .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

For information, the `git-reset` command resets the current branch to the specified commit (`HEAD^`, here).

As for the `--soft` option, it does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all, but requires them to be in a good order. This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed".

For more information, see the [`git-reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).